# Calling a member function of a class from a threaded dynamically loaded dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a class in a dll, which creates a thread for it. The functions that are exported from the dll should call the member functions of an object of the class. How would I make this happen?

I tried putting a global variable of the class in the .cpp file of the dll, and then make the exported functions call the member functions of that object, but with no use.

This is in Visual studio 2010 C++, and the dll is explicitly linked.

Comment: Did you export the class as well?

Comment: You mean exporting the class and then getting an object of the class in the main thread?

Comment: Yes.  Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: But then I need to include the header file for the class, no?

Comment: Yes you have to.  Including header any problem?  Unless you have header you cannot create the object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach and I figured how to make it work.